# Display color change

Tags: macbook-pro, display

The display on my MacBook Pro laptop has suddenly changed so that instead of white here I get a light yellow.  What has happened?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how this can happen all of a sudden, but I have a suggestion.
Launch System Preferences (fastest way is Apple Menu > System Preferences)
Click on `Display`
Click on the `Color` tab
Select `Color LCD` in the left column
If this does not reset the color, click the `Calibrate...` button on the left. This launches the Display Calibrator Assistant
At the step called `Target White Point` (see the current step name at the left of the window) make sure you select `Native`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had uneven colors on certain webpages on my Macbook Pro. Somehow it switched the profile (I guess during the upgrade to Sierra) to Apple RGB. Changing it back to "Color LCD" solved my problem too (without calibrating).

Answer (score -1):

I like Arc676's suggestion, however the yellowing you describe can also result from a loose video connection between the main board and the LCD screen. A search on "[macbook pro display connector loose yellow](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=klp&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&q=macbook%20pro%20display%20connector%20loose%20yellow&oq=macbook%20pro%20display%20connector%20loose%20yellow&gs_l=serp.3...9813.15973.0.16594.9.9.0.0.0.0.210.1359.1j7j1.9.0....0...1c.1.32.serp..5.4.690.a0qFi2KWeJI)" returns many horror stories, however, sometimes things just need a little jiggle to return to proper function.

Comment: Don't like this possibility, huh? Must be a pretty important opinion to supply after waiting 1.5 years to give it. Why not elucidate, rather than just giving the downvote of Doom?

Answer (score -2):

Was having the same problem. Display Calibration helps. :D just go to Sytem preferences, Display, Color Tab then Calibrate. :)